# Updating force directed graph with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I use a function to update nodes in a force directed graph, but I get the desired effect only in the second call. The function is called with a click event in a button.

[image]

To create the chart I use:

```
node = d3.select('#nodes').selectAll('circle')
    .data(data.nodes.slice(0, 5))
    .join('circle')
    .attr('cx', width / 2)
    .attr('cy', height / 2)
    .attr("fill", 'teal')
    .attr('r', d => 2 * d.score);

let simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .nodes(data.nodes.slice(0, 5))
    .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody())
    .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
    .on("tick", () => {
        node
            .attr("cx", d => d.x)
            .attr("cy", d => d.y);
    })
```

And the function used to update the chart is:

```
function update() {
    node = d3.select('#nodes').selectAll('circle')
        .data(data.nodes.slice(0, 10), d => d.id);

    // EXIT
    node.exit().remove();

    // UPDATE
    node
        .attr("fill", 'gray');

    // ENTER
    node.enter().append('circle')
        .attr("fill", 'crimson')
        .attr('cx', width / 2)
        .attr('cy', height / 2)
        .attr('r', d => 2 * d.score);

    simulation
        .nodes(data.nodes.slice(0, 10))
        .alpha(1)
        .restart();

}

d3.select('#update').on('click', update)
```

You can view a working demo here: https://codepen.io/ggojedap/pen/WNRYdZa

My question is, How can I get the new inserted nodes animated with one single click, not two? and what is causing this "delay" problem? Any advice is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Note: A very similar version using the new .join() approach is working OK but I need to really understand the reason this example requires 2 clicks.

Comment: These two answers of mine in the *duplicates* link explain the issue: your update selection is not changing the nodes' positions, only the enter selection does that (curiously, as I explain in the answers, your code would work with D3 v3 or previous).